Slack API keeps telling me to "reinstall your app"
I changed some scopes in hopes to enable the User Token (I already have the bot token). I get the message at the top of the screen stating I need to re-install the app.
Please reinstall your app for these changes to take effect.
I click the link and it takes me to where I can press the green button "Reinstall to..."
I press the button and then the Admin approves it.
Slackbot:
1)Your request to install AppName on Workspace has been sent for review.
2)Your request to install AppName has been approved. You can now install it from the App Directory.
But nothing changes and the message at the top of the screen continues to appear.
Any ideas?

I think this is a question better suited for Slack support forum
